# invalid JSON Variable Error

Tags: json

I'm pulling a JSON variable from a vendor that is supposed to show certain variables on an order, but I keep getting an error?

Does anyone have any clue what the error is on this piece of code?

PK  ƒš¬F               50562798074506.jsoneR]O1ü+M}s½/îˆ/à  b ñ¡6öZl{D$üw·àŒéÓíÌÎÎÎÞŽ~Ö\9á¶´ËZT›˜ûíRÆX;Š“_;gYÆ1mÑ
LùŽüåš¥lÐaÃé°xÊˆnÀX¡UtÐîŽ–µuºßÜaí^-µ/ÚÚ,y   –v_wTñ
pÔôXc¨À
ð#Vj©ÍÃ‘Pn-¢K­Ü
¯„D³tê@•BbùWæeü4!³ÁóŒÜ
&ÞŽƒ/‡Ä¹ÑúˆP+.¥%W‘WR"tÑ/úÑuÌÎ¶kïk†ýF`:jE÷oøöMBªCiÆ¢ Íó0ï„ÿV(ì,‚ày8õRoãt“·k(ÝÙª>œ
—µÜØÂqÇNÐÿe